# Как отцентрировать и масштабировать изображение?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть изображение, которое нужно поместить в область, которая будет занимать по ширине 100% ширины родителя и по высоте - 30% ШИРИНЫ родителя. При этом центрироваться и не деформироваться. При увеличении - уменьшении родителя - масштабироваться, но не искажаться. Вот как-то так:
[image: как-то так]

Comment: Начал делать тут: http://jsfiddle.net/dennila2/Lq7whsr6/ но застрял.

Comment: [Моя версия](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7whsr6/4/) с шириной в 100% от родителя, с высотой в 30% от ширины.

Comment: @Regent, Ваше решение меня полностью удовлетворило! Если оформите как ответ - я смогу отметить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Картинка указана как фон блока (`<div class="img-wrapper">`) с помощью `background-image: url(URL)`
- Высота в 30% от ширины блока задаётся с помощью `padding-bottom: 30%`
- Для растягивания картинки по блоку используется `background-size: cover`
- Для указания какую часть картинки отображать используется `background-position: 0 35%`

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="img-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.img-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 35%;
    background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTok9GAMciVqTTlxgSojXP8yPNAt1a0iyKexU7YCDEYFr1UgrGo');
}
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7whsr6/4/).

Answer (score 3):

А что если изображение сделать не `img`, а `background-image` у `div`?

Тогда будут работать [background-position](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position).

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7whsr6/2/) примерное решение...

**UPD** (по просьбам трудящихся)

[Вот реализация](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7whsr6/3/) с растяжкой картинки в div.

Comment: Добавил примерное решение)

Comment: Апдейт сделал...

Comment: Я добавил `background-size: cover;`, это растягивает картинку по диву. Дальше - использование предложенных свойств - дело техники.

Comment: Да, в конечном счете `background-size: cover;` оказался ничуть не менее важным, чем `background-image` и `background-position`.

Comment: Премного благодарен всем ответившим! Вы мне очень помогли!